# PAM: how to enforce AD group membership during login

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap

We use Active Directory (2003 and 2008) for all our users (70% Linux, 30% Windows). Normal user authentication works fine. I now have a situation where on a particular server I need to restrict the users that can login to members of a particular group in ADS. So I created the group and added the users in. Then I set in pam_ldap.conf

```
pam_groupdb cn=<group>,ou=Applications,dc=<domain>,dc=<tld>
```

and

```
pam_member_attribute memberOf
```

However, this does not seem to make any difference. I stopped nscd (just in case), but I can still log in using credentials of a user who is not a member of this group. Does anybody have experience with this?

There are other workarounds, but they are rather ugly and I would prefer not having to use them (e.g. extract all users via ldapsearch in a cron job and then put them into a list of allowed users, etc...). Oh, yes, I can see the members of this group just fine using ldapsearch. And I can see individual user's group memberships just fine, also using ldapsearch. I have put sshd on that server into debug mode, but the logs don't reveal anything useful. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What type of AD integration are you using? LDAP or Winbind?

Comment: Feels like you need to look into a LOCAL POLICIES of that particular Windows server. There's a setting which will prevent the users to login to the server if they're specifically denied that right. It's located at "Local Security Policy" -> "Local Policies" -> "Security Options" -> "Network Accces: ....". There's a plenty of settings there. (Hope I correctly understood your question.

Comment: This server is using LDAP.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that your settings have a typo in them.  I believe that pam_groupdb should instead be pam_groupdn.

from the manual:

```
$ man pam_ldap
```

...
**pam_groupdn** 
Specifies the distinguished name of a group to which a user must belong for logon authorization to succeed.

**pam_member_attribute** 
Specifies the attribute to use when testing a user’s membership of a group specified in the pam_groupdn option.
...